# Get specific range in S3 file with PowerShell AWS Tools

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3

I know this is possible with other sdks (boto, js sdk) but I have no idea how to do it with Powershell (can't find a -Range param).

How do I specify a range when getting an S3 Object with AWS tools?
I have a bucket containing 60k files and some of them (zip files) are corrupted and I know the missing byte is always at the end. So I'd like to check the zip signature in all those files without downloading it in its entirety.

Is it possible with PS? Or should I just use the JS SDK?

Comment: So you would like to go over all the objects in the bucket and get the zip signature of each one of them?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57835886/how-can-i-download-a-file-from-s3-via-powershell-without-installing-aws-sdk

Comment: I suppose that would be like using the Get-S3PreSignedURL cmdlet.

Comment: Yes, but you can get the file signature by the function they provided. You can share one of the zip files you want to test and I'll check it locally.